# How to synchronize databound controls across different forms

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I have a databound combobox in a toolbar of the main application. I also have a non-modal form with various controls databound to the same dataset. How do I make the combo control the position of the form's CurrencyManager?

**Update** 
Looks like simply sharing the BindingSource between forms works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you handle `CurrencyManager` event and change the combo from it?

Don't expect much of databinding architecture here - there will be some things that you will be forced to do 'by hand'.

Comment: Yes I was hoping not to have to write event handlers.

Comment: I see that you solved your problem - however, in the long run, try not to depend too much on binding.